# most pythonic way to interate a finite but arbitrary number of time through list values

Tags: python, iterator, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to optimize for a certain outcome genetic algorithm-style.

I provide a seed value as input to a function, which does some transformations and returns a "goodness value". I then pick the best seed values, and repeat the process until I've got a winner.

The challenge I've run into is that I want to run a finite number of trials for each step (say, 100 max) and the number of seed values changes widely from run to run. So just using a for loop to look through a list of seed values won't work for me.

Here is the solution I came up with to deal with a list not being an infinite iterator:

```
iterations = 100
rlist = list(d.keys())

    for lt in (itertools.repeat(rlist)):
        d = gatherseedvalues(directory)
        seed = random.choice(lt)
        goodness = goodnessgracious(seed)
        goodnessdict[seed] = goodness
        if len(goodnessdict) > iterations:
            break
```

Is there a more Pythonic way of doing this - both in terms of getting around the iterator restriction and the looping strategy?

Also, is using the `len(goodnessdict)` methodology appropriate or is there a more Pythonic way to break the loop?

Comment: Where is goodnessdict initialised? You just want to iterate over the first 100 items in rlist right? Also correct me if I am wrong, you want to have 100 items to process in rlist even if len(rlist)<100.?

Comment: seems like you just want `while True`: instead of your `for` loop, no?

Comment: Do you want to take a random sample of `seed` values from `rlist`? Your code doesn't appear to handle repeated seeds well (the result from a later use overwrites the result from any previous one), but is that something you want to allow? If @shshank has it right and `len(rlist)` might be less than `iterations`, you're current code would run forever, but it's not clear what you'd want to do instead.

Comment: @shshank rlist is arbitrarily long - if it has a length of ten, i'd want to iterate through it 10x (100 total attempts). if it has a length of 500, i'd want to process the first 100 items.

Comment: @Blckknght the "goodness" for any seed is not the same each time, but the possible values are constrained. i'm doing a series of transformations which have bounds, so if I infinitely passed in the same seed i'd get the same values. so what i'm looking to do is sample those possible goodness values based on a selection of seeds, throw out the worst ones, and eventually get a top seed as a form of optimization. I should allow for multiple seeds - so i'll edit for that. but the larger question of how to do the repeated iterations remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> rlist is arbitrarily long - if it has a length of ten, i'd want to iterate through it 10x (100 total attempts). if it has a length of 500, i'd want to process the first 100 items.

What you're looking for is `itertools.cycle` and `itertools.islice`:

```
for item in itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(rlist), iterations):
    # do something with item from rlist
```

This will iterate `iterations` times, taking an item from `rlist` on each go, starting over at the start if it reaches the end of the list.

Here's an example with a `range`:

```
for x in itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(range(4)), 10):
    print(x)
```

This will print:

```
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
0
1
```

Comment: thank you! this definitely makes more sense than what i'd attempted

Answer (score 1):

I agree with one of the comments.  In python the `do ... while` concept is generally approached (using a few of your variable names) as:

```
while True:
  if len(goodnessdict) > iterations:
    break
  # The rest of your code for the loop body here.
```

Is the result of `goodnessgracious(seed)` determinate?  I.E, does it always produce the same output for the same seed?  If so, your function shouldn't ever need to check the goodness for a single seed more than once and you could also improve the loop with this:

```
while True:
  seed = random.choice(lt)
  if seed in goodnessdict:
    continue
```